# Using jQuery click() method to trigger another element's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am working on a client site where they needed a "fake" Add To Cart button. When a user clicks the fake one, a few other things must happen behind the scenes and then we trigger the "real" add to cart button being clicked.

The problem is, after the line of code to "click" the real button, there is a long delay before the Add To Cart action goes in to action. Here is a simplified version of what I am using, also diagrammed in the image below.

```
 $('.double-subscription-option-column .new-product-atc').on('click',function(){
  /* other stuff here, but even when I remove these other things */
  /* the delay still happens */
  $('.button--add-to-cart').click(); 
 });
```

The page I'm working on is here: https://reprisehealth.com/products/custom-bottle
The real Add To Cart button is hidden, but if I unhide it and click it directly, the click events kick in immediately.

**My question is**, has anybody ever had an issue where using the jquery .click() method creates a huge (3-6 seconds) delay before clicking the target button?

[image: simplified flow]

Comment: I think something similar happened to me on a select field n I ended up just giving css height attribute of 0 px of the select so the trigger still works.

Comment: so you resolved it then ? you could also use ```.trigger( "click" );```

Comment: I did not. I will try `.trigger("click");` and see if that is faster than `.click();`